# Working MDB example in JBoss 7.0.1?

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0, jboss7.x, message-driven-bean

Here's an EJB3 MDB that used to work for me in JBoss 5.1:

```
@TransactionAttribute( TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED )
@org.jboss.ejb3.annotation.Depends("jboss.messaging.destination:service=Topic,name=IncomingArticleNotifications")
@MessageDriven(
    activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName="destinationType", propertyValue="javax.jms.Topic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName="destination", propertyValue="topic/IncomingArticleNotificationsDest"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName="subscriptionDurability", propertyValue="Durable"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName="messageSelector", propertyValue ="type='IncomingArticleNotification'")
    }
)
public class IncomingArticleHandler implements MessageListener
{
    [...]
}
```

Try as I might, I can't migrate this to JBoss **7.0.1**. JMS is set up OK, and I can publish to the destination OK (from my main JAR), but my EJB listener just isn't listening. I get **no deploy or runtime errors** for my EJB / WAR / EAR:

```
01:02:40,600 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) Starting deployment of "product-ear-1.0-SNAPSHOT.ear"
01:02:41,752 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Starting deployment of "product-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"
01:02:41,753 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) Starting deployment of "product.war"
```

I've also fixed the **JNDI names**, as per instructions, so here's what I have now:

```
// Ignore for now: @TransactionAttribute( TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED )
@ResourceAdapter("ejb3-rar.rar")    // ??? As per docs. No idea what this should be, an attempt to get something working.
@MessageDriven(
    activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName="destinationType", propertyValue="javax.jms.Topic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName="destination", propertyValue="java:/topic/IncomingArticleNotificationsDest"),    // updated
        @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName="subscriptionDurability", propertyValue="Durable")
        // Ignore for now: @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName="messageSelector", propertyValue ="type='IncomingArticleNotification'")
    }
)
public class IncomingArticleHandler implements MessageListener
{
    [...]
}
```

Setting all loggers to `ALL` before deploying reveals that the only time my MDB classes are mentioned is when the `org.jboss.vfs.util.SuffixMatchFilter` sees them - that can't be good.

I've been following the issue of [MDB support since 7.0.0](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-455) and have read through dozens of JIRAs, not to mention the migration guide, EJB3 docs and so on, but I'm left confused. I know MDBs *should* work in 7.0.1, but is the above doable? I think mine is quite a simple case, so does anyone have a simple working example, a single document that states exactly what does / doesn't work in 7.0.1, or a migration guide?

Edit: just thought I'd add that this is my only EJB, so this is probably as much an EJB problem as a JMS/MDB one.

**Updates:**

I can deploy a dummy `@Stateless` with no problems, but no combination of `@MessageDriven`/`@ActivationConfigProperty` has had any effect at all (bodging the `destinationType` to `javax.jms.XXX` produces no errors!). I've tried setting the destination property to all possible JNDI combinations.

I've checked my `standalone.xml` against `standalone-preview.xml` and there are no substantial differences.

The nearest I get to any kind of error is this:

```
00:53:25,886 DEBUG [org.hornetq.ra.Util] (MSC service thread 1-4) org.jboss.as.messaging.jms.TransactionManagerLocator from [Module "org.hornetq.ra:main" from local module loader @15a62c31 (roots: /Users/andrewregan/Desktop/jboss-as-7.0.1.Final/modules)]: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.messaging.jms.TransactionManagerLocator from [Module "org.hornetq.ra:main" from local module loader @15a62c31 (roots: /Users/andrewregan/Desktop/jboss-as-7.0.1.Final/modules)]
at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:191)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:358)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:307)
at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:101)
at org.hornetq.ra.Util.locateTM(Util.java:261) [hornetq-ra-2.2.7.Final.jar:]
at org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter.locateTM(HornetQResourceAdapter.java:1555) [hornetq-ra-2.2.7.Final.jar:]
at org.hornetq.ra.HornetQResourceAdapter.start(HornetQResourceAdapter.java:210) [hornetq-ra-2.2.7.Final.jar:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [:1.6.0_26]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [:1.6.0_26]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [:1.6.0_26]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [:1.6.0_26]
at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.startContext(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:339) [ironjacamar-deployers-common-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:1883) [ironjacamar-deployers-common-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
at org.jboss.jca.deployers.common.AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.createObjectsAndInjectValue(AbstractResourceAdapterDeployer.java:825) [ironjacamar-deployers-common-1.0.3.Final.jar:1.0.3.Final]
at org.jboss.as.connector.services.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator.doDeploy(ResourceAdapterActivatorService.java:140) [jboss-as-connector-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.as.connector.services.ResourceAdapterActivatorService.start(ResourceAdapterActivatorService.java:93) [jboss-as-connector-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.1.Final]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1765) [jboss-msc-1.0.0.GA.jar:1.0.0.GA]
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ClearTCCLTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2291) [jboss-msc-1.0.0.GA.jar:1.0.0.GA]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_26]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_26]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) [:1.6.0_26]
```

Might that be a problem? I get that by adding `@ResourceAdapter(value="hornetq-ra.rar")` as I've seen suggested elsewhere.

Comment: Not sure, but `propertyValue="java:/topic/IncomingArticleNotificationsDest"`
 looks a little suspicious to me. Are you sure that's correct ? EJB 3.1 portable JNDI names would look like `java:<xyz>/topic/...` where xyz might be one of (global,app,module)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm now specifying `java:/global/topic/IncomingArticleNotificationsDest` in the MDB, but JBoss always deploys the topics under just `java:/` (in every single example I've seen, the input format it expects in `standalone.xml` is "`topic/XYZ`"). The net result is that my MDBs still don't get invoked. (BTW, I created a dummy `@Stateless` bean and that deploys fine.)

Comment: Looks like some [startup config like this](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-application-server/327-developing-mdb-with-jboss-as-7.html) is required with AS-7.0.1

Comment: I don't think it's that, I've already got the `urn:jboss:domain:messaging:1.0` section from `standalone-preview.xml` in my `standalone.xml`, but I'll try running the example from scratch and see what happens. What I don't understand is that - even if I have specified the wrong JNDI name in my `@MessageDriven` - my MDBs are completely ignored. No deploy errors, nothing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally managed to solve this myself. JNDI was a red-herring. I didn't need to upgrade to JBoss 7.1.0alpha, nor did I need to change my project to use Java EE 6 deployment (moving my EJBs into the WAR).

In the end, all I needed to do was turn **off** JBoss's EJB3 "lite" mode (this was set to true in the standalone-preview.xml I copied from). Presumably MDBs are not supported in that mode. As soon as I did this, my MDBs became visible.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.1" lite="false">
    [...]
</subsystem>
```

My working MDB now looks like this:

```
@TransactionAttribute( TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED )
@MessageDriven(
    activationConfig = {
        @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName="destinationType", propertyValue="javax.jms.Topic"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName="destination", propertyValue="java:/topic/IncomingArticleNotificationsDest"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName="subscriptionDurability", propertyValue="Durable"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName="messageSelector", propertyValue ="type='IncomingArticleNotification'"),
        @ActivationConfigProperty( propertyName="clientID", propertyValue="myValue")    // See: http://jgurukulam.blogspot.com/2011/09/jboss-7.html
    }
)
public class IncomingArticleHandler implements MessageListener
{
    [...]
}
```

**UPDATE:**

"EJB lite" mode [has been removed](https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as/commit/2b47bdab2850f015633962338c8545287b4ff19d) !

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the last post.
But I still have this problem with JBoss 7.0.2.Final even if I set lite="false".
What JBoss version must be used to have MDB working ??
Thks

Comment: I'd suggest removing your "lite" attribute altogether, as the default is false, plus it gets de-supported anyway. I'd also recommend carefully checking your standalone.xml against standalone-full.xml to make sure there aren't any discrepancies that might cause EJB/EJB3/JMS to not work.